# How to pass apostrophe (') in NuSOAP?

Tags: php, nusoap

I am trying to pass an argument containing apostrophe character to function call but apparently it is being stripped out. Here's what I am doing:

```
$input = array(
  'kod_modelu' => "187'",
  'nr_nadwozia' => '00552889'
);

$result = $client->call('certyfikat_gwarancji_dane_pobierz', $input);
var_dump($result);
```

And in output I'm getting:

```
'kod_modelu' => string '187' (length=3)
'nr_nadwozia' => string '00552889' (length=8)
```

(I am repeating input in output and apostrophe is being stripped out).

How can I solve this?

EDIT: Here's a code to reproduce the issue:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/h07XqCAP)

Comment: have you looked at turning the debugger on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, case closed.

PHP 5.2.6 is the issue (referring to [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996)). Upgrading to the latest version of 5.2.x branch solves the problem.

Comment: Nice find, that would look more like the problem to me, I could not see anything in the source so it had to be something internal :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but since SOAP is XML based your quotes must be converted to XML entities somewhere.
I have no experience with nuSOAP, but a single quote's XML entity value is: `&apos;`.

Refer to the PHP function: [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: i have been reading the soruce and tracing the route the string takes and i can't see where its changing, but yea possibly if this is the response XML is changing it and then when its re-parsed its changed to an integer.